# Django Messages analogue in Java

Tags: java, message

Is there analogue of Django Messages Framework (or RoR flash messages) in Java?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

I want to show a message for user one time.

Comment: You may want to go and accept answers for some of the questions you have asked in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Grails, as an example, it is easily possible using the flash scope (like this question denotes : [Grails flash scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343898/grails-flash-scope)).

However, notice that any framework would allow you to do that, as that kind of scope is simply an extension of the request : by putting your message in the request attributes, you'll have it displayed only for the currently processed request.